# laravel 5.6 filter entered data in form

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm using laravel 5.6 and I need to filter my input.
laravel has pretty beautiful validation system . I'm wondering is there any way that instead of showing error when inputs are not what we want according to rules, remove those incorrect results. like example below 
this is my rule

```
$this->validate($request , [
        'room_attributes.*.title'      => 'required' ,
        'room_attributes.*.value'      => 'required' ,

    ]);
```

these are the data that I receive from the form

```
  "room_attributes" => array:6 [▼
0 => array:2 [▼
  "title" => "title 1"
  "value" => "val1"
]
1 => array:2 [▼
  "title" => "title2"
  "value" => "val2"
]
2 => array:2 [▼
  "title" => "title3"
  "value" => null
]
3 => array:2 [▼
  "title" => null
  "value" => "val4"
]
4 => array:2 [▼
  "title" => null
  "value" => null
]
5 => array:2 [▼
  "title" => null
  "value" => null
]
]
```

and with the current rule, I receive these errors

```
The room_attributes.3.title field is required.
The room_attributes.4.title field is required.
The room_attributes.5.title field is required.
The room_attributes.2.value field is required.
The room_attributes.4.value field is required.
The room_attributes.5.value field is required.
```

but I want to filter my data so I filter my inputs and receive this array as result (the only ones that have both title and value filled )

```
  0 => array:2 [▼
  "title" => "title 1"
  "value" => "val1"
]
1 => array:2 [▼
  "title" => "title2"
  "value" => "val2"
]
```

dose laravel provide functionality like that? either laravel itself or some third party library?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$data = $request->all();

$data['room_attributes'] = collect($data['room_attributes'])->filter(function($item){
    return !is_null($item['title']) && !is_null($item['value']);
})->toArray();

Validator::make($data, [
    'room_attributes.*.title' => 'required',
    'room_attributes.*.value' => 'required',
])->validate();
```

More info on the filter collection method: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-filter

Comment: hi. it's not just this model and I don't want to write a filter method for each data to validate it. I'm seeking for functionality in laravel or third-party library (if exist) to filter it in a clean way. like the way, I validate in laravel.

Comment: You could check out this collection macro: https://m.dotdev.co/use-laravel-validator-while-filtering-collections-e4e753d40b99 or perhaps you could put either into a Middleware which would be more reusable.